# Upgrade to Sonoma broke all my Karabiner bindings

Tags: keyboard, karabiner, sonoma

Yesterday I upgraded my Mac to Sonoma.
As any major MacOS update, this one as well messes up with my Karabiner bindings.

I had the following:
[image]

Neither of them is working anymore.
My Karabiner-Elements is on the latest version: **14.12.0**

Any ideas?

Comment: If you add a new binding (for anything, just to test), does the new one work?

Comment: Nope. But I did a workaround and it worked. I deleted Karabiner-Elements and all its sub-files (used AppCleaner for this). Restarted my Mac. Reinstalled the app and gave the permissions anew and it works...